# selecting matching value from one table to multiple values in another

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, inner-join

```
    cars                 models
car_id  car       car_id   model_id  model
   1    ford         1         1      mustang
   2    fiat         1         2      focus
   3    toyota       1         3      escort
                     2         4      500
                     2         5      spider
                     3         6      tacoma
```

The two tables I have are much more complicated so I took this code from another users question, It is almost what I want, but I don't know how to get the output to format with PHP correctly

```
SELECT c.Car, m.Model_id, m.Model
FROM models m
INNER JOIN car c ON c.Car_id = m.Car_id
WHERE m.Car_id = (SELECT Car_id FROM models WHERE Model = 'Escort');

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$model = $row['Model'];
$vehicle = $row['Car'];

    ford mustang
    ford focus
    ford escort
```

What I am trying to get is

```
    ford
        mustang
        focus
        escort
```

I have posted my updated attempt below, which works, but I bet you fine people could make it prettier.

```
$sql = "
SELECT c.Car, m.Model_id, m.Model 
FROM models m 
INNER JOIN car c   
ON     c.Car_id = m.Car_id
WHERE m.Car_id = '1' ";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$vehicle[$row['Car']][] = $row['Model'];
}

echo "<table>";
foreach( $vehicle as $value => $key )
{echo '<tr><td>'.$value.'</td></tr>'; 
foreach( $key as $mod) 
{echo '<tr><td>'.$mod.'</td></tr>';}}

}
```

Results in:
ford
mustang
focus
escort

Comment: I believe you already have your desired result. You just need to properly format it in frontend.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want an array with the key as the car type. Loop you're results and append to an array as necessary.

Ex:

```
vehicle=[];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (!array_key_exists($row['Car'], $vehicle)){
        $vehicle[$row['Car']] = [];
    }
    $vehicle[$row['Car']][] = $row['Model'];
}
```

Output will look like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["Ford"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "focus",
    [1]=>
    string(6) "escort"
  }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't get around the error 'array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in', so I got rid of the `if (!array_key_exists($row['Car'], $vehicle)){
        $vehicle[$row['Car']] = [];` bit of code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$mo1 = "";

$sql = "SELECT c.Car, m.Model_id, m.Model FROM models m INNER JOIN car c ON c.Car_id = m.Car_id
WHERE m.Car_id = (SELECT Car_id FROM models WHERE Model = 'Escort')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $model = $row['Model'];
    $vehicle = $row['Car'];

 if($mo1 != $mo){$data.="<tr>
                            <td>$model</td>
                        </tr>";
                }

$data.="<tr>
            <td>$vehicle</td>
           </tr>";

$mo1=$mo;

}

?>
```